# look for an object in an array of object return undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, find

Hy,
I have the following array of objects, I wish that the id returns to me its object. How could I do?

```
    prodotto=[
{
    categoria:"primi",
    prodotti:[
    {
        id:1,
        nome:"pasta",
        prezzo:12,
        qta:0
    },{
        id:2,
        nome:"gnocchi",
        prezzo:12,
        qta:0
    }
    ]
},
{
    categoria:"secondi",
    prodotti:[  {
        id:3,
        nome:"salsiccia",
        prezzo:12,
        qta:0
    },{
        id:4,
        nome:"frittura",
        prezzo:12,
        qta:0
    }]

}

];
```

for example, after id 2 returns
{
            id:2,
            nome:"gnocchi",
            prezzo:12,
            qta:0
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` and `.find()` methods to find the desired object.

```js
let data = [{
  categoria:"primi",
  prodotti:[
    { id:1, nome:"pasta", prezzo:12, qta:0 },
    {id:2, nome:"gnocchi", prezzo:12, qta:0 }
]}, {
  categoria:"secondi",
  prodotti:[
    { id:3, nome:"salsiccia", prezzo:12, qta:0 },
    {id:4, nome:"frittura", prezzo:12, qta:0 }
]}];

let locator = (objId) => [].concat(...data.map(({ prodotti }) => prodotti))
                           .find(( {id} ) => id === objId);

console.log(locator(2));
```

You may also store the intermediate results in another array to easily iterate over them and find the resultant object.

```js
let data = [{
  categoria:"primi",
  prodotti:[
    { id:1, nome:"pasta", prezzo:12, qta:0 },
    {id:2, nome:"gnocchi", prezzo:12, qta:0 }
]}, {
  categoria:"secondi",
  prodotti:[
    { id:3, nome:"salsiccia", prezzo:12, qta:0 },
    {id:4, nome:"frittura", prezzo:12, qta:0 }
]}];

let _data = [].concat(...data.map(({ prodotti }) => prodotti));

let locator =  (objId) => _data.find(( {id} ) => id === objId);

console.log(locator(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) like this:

```js
const prodotto = [{categoria:"primi",prodotti:[{id:1,nome:"pasta",prezzo:12,qta:0},{id:2,nome:"gnocchi",prezzo:12,qta:0}]},{categoria:"secondi",prodotti:[{id:3,nome:"salsiccia",prezzo:12,qta:0},{id:4,nome:"frittura",prezzo:12,qta:0}]}]

const output = prodotto.flatMap(a => a.prodotti).find(p => p.id === 2)
console.log(output)
```

If `flatMap` isn't [supported in your browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility), use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const prodotto = [{categoria:"primi",prodotti:[{id:1,nome:"pasta",prezzo:12,qta:0},{id:2,nome:"gnocchi",prezzo:12,qta:0}]},{categoria:"secondi",prodotti:[{id:3,nome:"salsiccia",prezzo:12,qta:0},{id:4,nome:"frittura",prezzo:12,qta:0}]}]

const output = [].concat(...prodotto.map(a => a.prodotti))
                  .find(p => p.id === 2)

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getObjById(id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < prodotto.length; i++) {
    var obj = prodotto[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < obj.prodotti.length; j++) {
      var inn = obj.prodotti[j];
      if (inn.id === id) return inn;
    }
  }
}

console.log(getObjById(4));
```

It's an old version of javascript, it's supported for ECMA5.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use the `Array#reduce` method combined with `Array#find`. This allows you to iterate through each `prodotto` array item and "reduce" this array down to the result that you're looking for (ie an item in the `prodotti` sub-array with `id` matching `2`).

During each `reduce` iteration, the following logic allows you to either "pass through" a previously found result, or invoke a search for the sub-array item (via the `Array#find` method):

```
// If currentResult defined, return that, otherwise look for a matching item
// in prodotti sub-array which will become the currentResult for subsequent
// iterations:
return currentResult || item.prodotti.find(subitem => {
  return subitem.id === 2;
});
```

These two ideas combined into a working solution are shown as the following:

```js
var prodotto = [{
    categoria: "primi",
    prodotti: [{
      id: 1,
      nome: "pasta",
      prezzo: 12,
      qta: 0
    }, {
      id: 2,
      nome: "gnocchi",
      prezzo: 12,
      qta: 0
    }]
  },
  {
    categoria: "secondi",
    prodotti: [{
      id: 3,
      nome: "salsiccia",
      prezzo: 12,
      qta: 0
    }, {
      id: 4,
      nome: "frittura",
      prezzo: 12,
      qta: 0
    }]

  }

];

// Use reduce to search all sub arrays of the prodotto array
var result = prodotto.reduce((currentResult, item) => {

  // return the current result found, or if none yet return
  // the result (if any) that is found in the prodotti sub array
  return currentResult || item.prodotti.find(subitem => {
    return subitem.id === 2;
  });

}, undefined)

console.log(result)
```